# Ethernet Indicator led on pi 3B+ not glowing

Tags: ethernet, led, pi-3b+, win32diskimager, minibian

I am a newbie to Raspberry Pi and recently bought *Raspberry pi 3 B+*. 
I first downloaded and burn the minibian on sd card as some course suggested minibian.
But whenever I connect pi with power, only pwr led glows(doesn't blink) and every other doesn't. After connecting to router through ethernet, no led lights up, not even ethernet indicator.

I searched for some same problems on various sites and most of those forums concluded that there is some hardware failure and they replaced the pi with some new one and it started working then. But I don't think that my pi is dead or broken, it came from one of the official supplier of pi in India(*element14*).
I think there's is something missing that most people neglected.

**Following are the steps that I followed:**

- Deleted every partition on sd card and made a new one.
- Then formatted the whole partition.
- burnt iso image on sd card with *win32diskimager* 1.0.
- Inserted sd card in pi and powered it on.

**What's the issue? Why leds of pi and ethernet indicator not glowing?**

P.S. : Don't mind the progress, I am a noob to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Not sure if minibian is actually compatible with the 3B+ yet. To test if your Pi is OK download Raspbian Stretch (Lite or Desktop), write it to the SD card and boot.

Comment: Yes it worked! so would Raspbian be complex enough for a newbie like me? or should I buy another older version of Pi for minibian?

Comment: Its now showing " Network error : connection refused " when I select my PI  ip to launch in PuTTY. What is going on here?

Comment: I would use Raspbian until you got some experience. It's the best supported OS for the Pi. Regarding connection refused: you need to activate SSH before you can use it.

Comment: To use *ssh* look at the official documentation for Raspbian: [SSH (Secure Shell)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/). It is always a good way to look at the foundations web site. They provide many start up information for beginners. But don't hesitate to ask also here. You are welcome.

Comment: 0


That was the problem as Dirk said in comments section. My problem is solved now. Thanks!